# Can I resize an image without distorting its pixels?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm taking a look at python imaging library and trying to resize a pixel art with it but whenever I resize it, it gets distorted and weird, is there some way of keeping the pixels' proportions?

Here you can see an example of what I want to do:

[original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrR0R.png)

[resized image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3tw0.png)

But with PIL it gets like this:

[image resized with PIL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQscZ.png)

Here's the code that's being used:

```py
from PIL import Image
original = Image.open("original.png")
resized = original.resize((1024,1024))
resized.save("resized.png")
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @usr2564301 thanks, it works.

Answer (score -1):

You will likely want to make sure you maintain the aspect ratio by getting the width and height of the original image.  Use a fixed value for the new width and divide the fixed value by the width (for example) to get a multiplier (you could also just use a multiplier on both the width and height directly if you don't have a fixed width or height in mind).  Multiply the height by that multiplier and you will have the new height.  For example:

```
from PIL import Image
original = Image.open("original.png")

new_width = 1024
multiplier = new_width / original.width
new_height = original.height * multiplier

resized = original.resize((new_width, new_height))
resized.save("resized.png")
```

Do note that changing the size of a rastor image significantly will affect the quality.

Comment: While maintaining the aspect ratio is a helpful suggestion, it doesn't address the main issue the OP is asking about: the blurriness of the scaled-up image.